# In read_csv(), how to combine use `col_names = TRUE` and `col_character`

Tags: r, tidyverse, readr

In readr, where combine using parameter `col_names = TRUE` and `col_character` as below code3, it's failed and the error message as attached image. Anyone can help on this ? Thanks!

```
library(tidyverse)    
# code1 ok    
    read_csv("a,b,c
        1,2,3
        4,5,6",col_character)
    
    # code2 ok      
        read_csv("a,b,c
        1,2,3
        4,5,6",col_names = TRUE)
    
    # code3 :failed   
        read_csv("a,b,c
        1,2,3
        4,5,6",col_names = TRUE,col_character)
```

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I got it , Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrap it around `cols`, e.g.

```
readr::read_csv("a,b,c
        1,2,3
        4,5,6",
  col_names = TRUE,
  col_types = readr::cols(.default = col_character())
)
```